# Facebook shows blank screen after login (facebook js api)

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

```
<body>
<script>
// Facebook Init
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.init({
   appId      : '...MYID...', // App ID
   channelUrl : 'channel.html', // Channel File
   status     : true, // check login status
   cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
   xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
});

// Additional initialization code here
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',
function(response) {
    alert('You liked the URL: ' + response);
}
);
};

</script>

<div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>(function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/de_DE/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=...MYID...";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

    <div id="player"></div>
    <div id="main">

    <div id="facebook" style="height:30px;">
    <div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.MYURL.com/about" data-send="true" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>
    </div>
```

Can somebody help? I am php programmer myself and just stuck with JS... I also considered the Php api, but actually it used to work, now it hangs all of sudden.. not sure what I did :(

Thanks!

Comment: OK i changed my code to exactly the code provided on http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/. The only thing that I found out is in the URL on the blank page (after log-in) it shows a different APP-ID then the one in my source: http://www.facebook.com/connect/uiserver.php?method=opt.inlike&app_id=...DIFFERENTAPPID...&display=popup&social_plugin=like&secure=false&protocol=http%3A&external_page_url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.MYURL.com%about&from_login=1&client_id=xxx&ext=1333021547&hash=AQArcSpK2V9MBfRz .. Any hints? :(

Comment: I nailed down the problem that is that in my popup window after the login I see a wrong APP-ID. When I change it to my app ID it works like supposed. Anybody knows where the problem could be?

Comment: When I use firebug to see my JS Files there is a oauth*** that answers with an error message. Guess it's something with the settings on facebook. I'll keep it posted so others can read too (if they fall into the same errors)

Comment: nobody in the meantime? Is there something I might have missed on the facebook site? URL's?

Comment: Experiencing the same thing on the site I'm working on for what it's worth. I'm beginning to think there's a problem with Facebook.

Comment: Me too. The strange thing this is it worked just fine yesterday and the day before. I changed a little on the script but now tried about every combination I can possibly make.. Let me know if you succeed..

Comment: This just started yesterday for me as well. See the link in my answer. Literally just started yesterday across 3 different servers at my company. And we didn't change anything. 

That APP ID you see in the URL that Firebug shows for the blank page (the 500 error URL) is actually a FB APP ID that they use for logins. It's the same ID for all of us, I believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the Facebook developer site. It would be a good place to track as this is possibly not you. I'm having the same issue and I'm using FBML tags and not iFrame or HTML5.

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/347759798609016

Something else to try is to try logging in, kill that window, then refresh the page. For me at least the "Like" button works after the refresh. So the login is successful, but the response from Facebook isn't.

Comment: Hi Preston, thanks for the link! Just wrote in the comments. Mike

Comment: I experience it with all facebook like buttons on other websites as well.

Comment: For what it's worth I went home last night, outside the confines of my corporate firewall, proxy, etc. I created a completely blank page that referenced my personal app that I created. Everything is brand new. I tried it with XFBML, HTML5 and iFrame. Each method failed. I'm not sure what more can be done on this other than raise the issue to Facebook. This page was empty of content and should have been easily reachable by Facebook.

Comment: Mike, check the bug listed earlier. https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/347759798609016 ---- 


Facebook says they're working on a fix.

Comment: There has been a change. At least in my case I the blank page doesn't pop up. Instead the like popup goes away, the like dialog pops up and then disappears and then the user would have to select "like" again. So they're making progress. Hopefully this isn't them being finished.

Comment: Working again!! (for me at least, how about you?)

Comment: Works now. And in that facebook bug link earlier they marked it fixed.